# RexgEx from .asp to Wordpress Not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, regex, wordpress, redirect

I have a very old site (Microsoft .asp) that I am rebuilding in WordPress. I am preserving the identical url structure on the new site.

Example: `https://example.org/directory/mypage.asp` TO `https://example.org/directory/mypage/`

I have written a RegEx for the pages that end in .asp as follows. (Using Redirection plugin)

Source URL

```
/(.*).asp
```

Target URL

```
/URL: /$1/
```

But it is not working as expected - the .asp link still resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that may need this - here is the correct RegEx.

Source URL: `^/(.*).asp`
Target URL: `/$1/`

RegEx: Checked